# Blazor Wasm Performance issue opening excel with npoi / closedXML

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, npoi

On a project WebAssembly i'm currently struggling with performance issues while reading XLSX file with NPOI or ClosedXML

The goal is to have a front end validation of the XLSX file before sending it to the back.

```
async Task ImportExcelFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    dataTable = new DataTable();

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new();

    await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    XSSFWorkbook xsswb = new(memoryStream);
    ISheet sheet = xsswb.GetSheetAt(0);
    IRow hr = sheet.GetRow(0);
    var rows = new List<string>();

    int cc = hr.LastCellNum;

    for (var j = 0; j < cc; j++)
    {
        ICell cell = hr.GetCell(j);
        dataTable.Columns.Add(cell.ToString());
    }

    for (var j = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); j <= sheet.LastRowNum; j++)
    {
        var r = sheet.GetRow(j);
        for (var i = r.FirstCellNum; i < cc; i++)
        {
            rows.Add(r.GetCell(i)?.ToString());
        }

        if (rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(rows.ToArray());
        }
        rows.Clear();
    }
}
```

Uploading an 1K rows  takes like 6/7 seconds to run  this line (110 KO)
Uploading an 13K rows takes between 30/40 seconds to run this line (1 MB)

```
    XSSFWorkbook xsswb = new(memoryStream);
```

I'm not sure with that to keep validation on front or to just send the stream to the back end and validate it here.

Is that normal it take so much time once ran on navigator side ?